# Using preg_match on array from POST checkbox values

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, preg-match

The problem I'm having is making preg_match work correctly for my array returned from my form.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="receiver-check[]" class="checkbox-id" value="Username 1 (123)">
<input type="checkbox" name="receiver-check[]" class="checkbox-id" value="Username 2 (456)">
<input type="checkbox" name="receiver-check[]" class="checkbox-id" value="Username 3 (789)">
```

So I wish to use preg_match on the values received through my form.
This is how I use it.

```
$msg_receivers = !empty($_POST['receiver-check']) && is_array($_POST['receiver-check']) ? $_POST['receiver-check'] : array();
    $receiverIds = array();
    foreach($msg_receivers as $receiver) {
        $receiverIds[] = preg_replace('/\((\d+)\)$/', "$1", $receiver);
    }
    $number_of_receivers = count($receiverIds);
    $while_count = 0;
    while($number_of_receivers >= ($while_count + 1)){
        $sql = <<< EOF
        INSERT INTO private_messages (
        message_subject,
        message_content,
        message_deliver,
        message_receive,
        message_status,
        message_datetime,
        message_to_stab
        )VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,'2',?,?);
EOF;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Feil i database<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Feilmelding:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssiiii",$message_subject,$message_content, $_SESSION['user_id'],$receiverIds[$while_count],$message_datetime,$message_to_stab);
        $stmt->execute() or die("noe gikk galt");
        $msg_num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        if($msg_num_rows = 0){
            $msg = "Feilmelding: Klarte ikke å sende meldingen.";
        }
        else{
            $msg = "Meldingen har blitt sendt.";
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        $while_count ++;
    }
```

Then I use `$msg_receiver_query` to asign a value in the query INSIDE the while loop. 
What I currently receive in my database is 0 and 1. Nothing else. What would the correct `preg_match` be for me to output JUST the numbers inside the paranthesis? and is there a more effective solution to this problem of mine?

Comment: Aside from the slightly odd way you've written that loop, you've missed off the pattern boundaries from the RegExp : a simple `/\(\d+\)$/` should do you.

Comment: Should I use foreach instead?

Comment: I would - be a much simpler loop; `foreach($msg_receivers as $sReceiverValue) { ... }` ... I'd validate `$_POST['receiver-check']` as well against `!empty()` and `is_array()` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I still just get 1 as output in my database. Can we talk in chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you **don't** want to match, you want to extract just a portion of each `$_POST['receiver-check']` value - so `preg_replace()` would be the right function to use.

```
$msg_receivers = !empty($_POST['receiver-check']) && is_array($_POST['receiver-check']) 
             ? $_POST['receiver-check'] : array();

$receiverIds = array();

foreach($msg_receivers as $receiver) {
  $receiverIds[] = preg_replace('/^.*\((\d+)\)$/', "$1", $reciever);
}
```

That should give you an array of reciever ids ($receiverIds) like:

```
array(
  [0] => 123, 
  [1] => 456, 
  [2] => 789
  );
```

Comment: How would I bind this to a query? I suppose $receiverIds[0] would be = 123 and 2 = 456?

Comment: Pretty much - but if you're using bound parameters you'll need to pass the variables by reference ... if you're using PDO you could use `bindValue()` instead.

Comment: I tried your solution. I Only get 0 in my database when receiver-check is selected. How come? the checkbox name is `receiver-check[]`

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: It's working! Thank you! :) I've spent ages on this now!

Comment: No worries - glad it's sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

This way you can insert it in to your DB. but you will query your Db 3 times to insert 3 records.

```
<?php

//use your connection Data
$user = "root";
$pass = "***";
$host = "localhost";
$dbdb = "TestDataBase";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
    trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

//check if receiver-check is set or not
if(isset($_POST['receiver-check'])){
      $msg_receivers = $_POST['receiver-check'];


      // iterate through $msg_receivers
      foreach($msg_receivers AS $value){
          preg_match_all("/([0-9]{3})/", $value, $msg_receiver_query);

            //Query, just change the table name and columns to what ever you need.
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`) VALUES ('" .$msg_receiver_query[0][0] . "')";

            if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
                  echo 'Record(s) created successfully<br>';
            } else {
                  echo $sql . '"<br>"' . mysqli_error($connect);
            }
      }

}else{
      echo "nothing is set";
}
?>
```

Maybe a ittle to advanced but you can do this in **one** query aswell.

```
<?php

//use your connection Data
$user = "root";
$pass = "***";
$host = "localhost";
$dbdb = "TestDataBase";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
    trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

//check if receiver-check is set or not
if(isset($_POST['receiver-check'])){
      $msg_receivers = $_POST['receiver-check'];

      $inputArray = '';

      // iterate through $msg_receivers
      foreach($msg_receivers AS $value){
          preg_match_all("/([0-9]{3})/", $value, $msg_receiver_query);

          //insert all output in to an array
          $inputArray [] =  "('" . $msg_receiver_query[0][0] . "')";
      }

      //Insert all outputs in 1 query
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `testtable` (`column1`) VALUES " . implode(",",$inputArray) . "";

      if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
            echo 'Record(s) created successfully<br>';
      } else {
            echo $sql . '"<br>"' . mysqli_error($connect);
      }

}else{
      echo "nothing is set";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this count even if I use receiver-check[] in my name?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I have. I got 0 in my database.

Comment: I just output it in your browser this isn't inserting anything in your db. Just edit your question and show us your query.

Comment: Updated my answer with a query, just an example query you need to change it to fit your situation. I gave you 2 options: multiple queries or just 1 query.